# How to redirect web ui hosted under port X to mydomain.com/directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I tried redirecting my traffic so if anyone visits mydomain.com/directory, it will be the same as visiting mydomain.com:8080. Here's my .htaccess so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^directory "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\:8080%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Most likely I'm missing something important here.
If .htaccess can't do such things, can I achieve that by messing with config located in **/etc/apache2/?**

Also, is there a way to find said web ui file directory, so I can move it to mydomain.com/directory physically?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^directory(?:\/|$) http://example.com:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

One issue that might be causing this is that you are escaping a non-regex string, `"http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\:8080%{REQUEST_URI}"`.

I have added `(?:\/|$)` after `^directory` because the original will also pass `directoryxyz` to the backend server.